# getting an error in the pl/sql procedure for finding the name of the topper

Tags: mysql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

this is the procedure:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'procedure topperstudent
>   as
>   topper students.name%type' at line 1

```
create or replace procedure topperstudent
as
topper students.name%type;
begin
select name into topper from students where marks = (select max(marks) from 
students)enter code here
dbms_output.put_line(topper);
end;
/
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Your error message suggests you are using MySQL and not PL/SQL (as tagged), in which case I would be very surprised if PL/SQL Developer (also tagged) even started up. `create or replace procedure` and `%type` are Oracle syntax, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will through exception if there are more than one students with max marks.

Below code can be tried.

```
create or replace procedure topperstudent
as
topper students.name%type;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('topper Names :');
for Student_name in (select name from students where marks = (select max(marks) from 
students))
loop
dbms_output.put_line(Student_name.name);
end loop;
end;
```

Above code is assuming we have atleast one student data in the students table.

Else we could have a validation check of count of students in the students table and based on the count > 0 execute the for loop.

Comment: it is giving me this error after

topper students.name%type;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'procedure topperstudent

Comment: There is only one entry with maximum marks, still getting the error

Comment: try using varchar(50) instead of students.name%type and check; This above answer I have mentioned assuming PLSQL.